# Get JSON from joomla 2.5 website

Tags: android, json, mobile, web, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla catalog website and now I need to build a mobile app based on that website. Is there a possibility to get JSON from my site and what should I do and how do I do that? If anybody knows please help me!

Answer (score 3):

this is precisely what you need

http://docs.joomla.org/Generating_JSON_output

Answer (score 0):

May this help you:

You can 
get values from webservice using JSON and parsing. Just refer [this](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-how-parse)